# Form shows all the details of an element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form which shows posts per user. It works fine, only do I get this after it...

```
[#<User id: 1, email: "admin1@example.com", encrypted_password:...
```

So endresult is like this:

```
member14@example.com

[#<User id: 1, email: "admin1@example.com", encrypted_password:
```

The code I user in my view is like this:

```
 <div class="collaboratorbox">
  <%= form_for @wiki do |f| %>
    <%= @users.each do |user| %>
    <p><%= check_box_tag 'user_ids[]', user.id %>
    <%= label_tag 'user_ids[]', user.email %> </p>
    <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Save Collaborators" %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Any thoughts on how I can get rid of the [# ..... ] code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
<%= @users.each do |user| %>
```

To this

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
```

By using the equals you're telling rails to print to the screen